# Why does Hungary not follow the "usual Western naming system"?

Tags: names, hungary

In the "usual western system" (I'm not sure if there's a more formal name for this), we have given names first, then family names last. In contrast, in the "eastern system", the order is reversed.

Hungary follows the "eastern system". Why? What is the historical explanation for this anomaly?

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain what you are after beyond what is on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_name#Name_order) and linked articles?

Comment: @sempaiscuba: The only explanation I can find on that page or any of the linked articles is simply the claim that "Hungary (the original homeland of the Hungarians was likely in Asia, at the southern foothills of the Ural Mountains)". I am not satisfied with this explanation because to my knowledge, the cultures (currently) near the southern Urals do not follow the Hungarian/eastern name order either.

Comment: Please edit that information into your question. As for the 'policy' on History:SE, you might find it helpful to review the [site tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: @JohnDallman - it seems that the Wikipedia article contains only a few general descriptions (including the "eastern/western" naming-duality) that are not satisfactory as an explanation.

Comment: @cipricus I'm inclined to agree.  However, those 'general descriptions' would be a valid answer to the question as currently written, which is why the fact that they are not a sufficient explanation should have been included in the question by the OP.  When the information in a Wikipedia article is found to be deficient, _that deficiency_ should be the focus of the question.

Comment: Where is the line drawn? Must I also read every book and every Yahoo answer post and explain why I am not satisfied with each explanation? This is not the policy of most Stack Exchange sites, but somehow it is the requirement here.

Comment: @dtcm840 No, nobody expects you to "_read every book and every Yahoo answer post and explain why I am not satisfied with each explanation_", but we do like to see evidence of research. In this case, there is a reason given on Wikipedia, but that reason is insufficient (**although it would be a valid answer to the question as currently written!**). Just include what Wikipedia says in your question (quote and cite), say why it is inadequate (as you did in your comment above), and be clear about what it is that you are actually asking for.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86988/discussion-on-question-by-dtcm840-why-does-hungary-not-follow-the-usual-western).

Comment: @sempaiscuba: So, everyone else's comments are "moved to chat" (i.e. deleted), while four of your comments stay? Also, I never got any response from you about the Kenpeitai question.

Comment: @dtcm840 As the help text states, comments are to ask for more information or suggest improvements. The remaining comments are suggestions are suggestions for how you can bring your question on-topic for this site. I thought that Lars had already answered your Kenpeitai question, but I'll add my 2d worth in chat if you like.

Comment: @dtcm840 In the meantime, I'm closing this question for now, pending your edits, to prevent it attracting low quality answers in the interim.

Comment: @sempaiscuba: Oh OK. I offended you so now you're "punishing" me by closing this question. Awesome.

Comment: @dtcm840 I'm not offended, and this is not a punishment. As previously requested, please review the [site tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask]. When the question has been edited to bring it back on-topic I will retract my close vote.