# What is known about the origins of the "western given-name-first-surname-last system"?

Tags: india, names

I refer to the custom or "system" of having one's **given name first and family name/surname last**. I believe this is widely used in the west, with the exception of [Hungary](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/49853/why-does-hungary-not-follow-the-usual-western-naming-system) (and perhaps a few other Western communities).

This custom or "system" is in contrast to other naming systems, such as the "eastern system" (in which the order is reversed, used in China and the other Confucian societies), patronymics (e.g. Iceland), matronymics, and mononymics.

I apologize if I do not know the precise term for this; I have read the Wikipedia article ["Personal Name"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_name) but cannot find much other information on this. (See also [this other closed question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/49837/a-history-of-human-naming-systems) where I provided a little more context.)

---

Below is just some of my uninformed speculation:

I notice for example that North Indian names follow this "western system". This is in contrast to some parts of South India which uses a form of patronymy.

Might there then be any relation between the "western naming system" and the Indo-Europeans/Aryans? Or is this just a coincidence?

Comment: Have you checked up on the [Roman *naming system*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_naming_conventions), with a tripartite system consisting of praenomen, nomen, and cognomen? Spanish tradition is for a long list of names of patrilineal and matrilieneal ancestors. First establish that there even ***is*** a *Western naming system*.

Comment: Semitic naming systems also seem to have the first name first. I'd rather argue that it's the more logical way.

Comment: You may need to be more specific. There are several naming systems in Europe. Notably, some Nordic and Slavic peoples used the name of their father with a "daughter" or "son" suffix instead of a family name (and some still do). Do you mean the custom of having your personal name first and given name last (in contrast to naming systems such as Japan)?

Comment: Instead of creating a new question that is risking closing also you should try to improve the one about Hungarian - as well as this new one. It is clear that what you are interested mostly in is the Hungarian exception as you articulated in your first question. I think that shouldn't have been closed, as it only needed a bit of improvement. This one is too general I think, also a bit vague.

Comment: Lastname Firstname wouldn't be totally surprising to me in e.g. in Bavaria. I've also met that naming scheme in (northeastern) Italy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already highlighted in comments, the use of 'western naming system' is problematic so it is only possible to produce a fairly generalized answer for most of western Europe (and, by extension and to greatly varying degrees, areas subjected to European colonization -  primarily French and British).

In *[The Means of Naming: A social and cultural history of personal naming in western Europe](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/The_Means_of_Naming.html?id=VWBmAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y)* (1998), the author Stephen Wilson writes in his conclusion on the two millennia of personal naming he surveys:

> First, naming practices go through a limited number of long-term
>   phases. The Roman *tria nomina* develop in the Republican period and
>   survive into the Empire to be replaced for most classes by a Latin
>   single-name system. With the fall of Rome, this gives way—but not at
>   once—to a Germanic singlename system, in which names are composed of
>   specific elements and in which originally each person has a distinct
>   name. Only in the central medieval period is a second name introduced,
>   which becomes a fixed family name from around the fourteenth century,
>   though this process is delayed for much of the peasantry until later.
>   Once fixed from the medieval period, second names survive unchanged
>   down to the present.

A key (but far from only) reason for the spread of the practice of adopting a second name in the middle ages was the increasing use of fewer and fewer names.  This is well illustrated by this 1230 writ from [Henry III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_III_of_England) of England to the Sheriff of Essex concerning the confusion over who was responsible for a loan of 60 shillings from the exchequer. Was it

> from Richard son of William in the time of lord John the king our
>   father, was made to Richard son of William of Stapleford or to Richard
>   father of Robert of Tilbury; and if the same Richard, the father of
>   Robert...was called Richard son of William or Richard son of Robert?

*Cited by S. Wilson, The Means of Naming*

Thus, 'qualifiers' were introduced and, according to grammatical convention, this meant the use of copulatives (connecting words) such as *of* (*de*) and *the* (*le* or *l'*), followed by two of the most common 'qualifiers', place and occupation.

This took quite some to become standardized, though, and it should not be assumed that the son would have the same second name as the father, or even that a man would have only one way of styling himself. Wilson cites many examples, among which are:

- > Filippo Brunelleschi (1377–1446), the Florentine architect, was the
  >   son of Brunellesco di Lippo Lapi.
- > Ricardus filius Fyn (c.1160, Yorkshire) was later called Ricardus Fyn
- > Peros Moreuz le Basters, Peron Morel, or Peron Baster (1290)

Also, the practice of adopting a second name developed later among the peasantry:

> In most areas, the second name began among the nobility and percolated
>   downwards or outwards later. It penetrated the laity before the clergy
>   and was used by men before women. In other words, it was associated
>   with public life and certain functions within public life....Once the process began, it spread
>   geographically and socially because the underlying reasons repeated themselves
>   but also through emulation.

*Source: Wilson*

The practice of listing names alphabetically by second name developed much later:

> An indicator of the continuing importance of the first name as the
>   name is found in early name listings. Febvre noted that in
>   sixteenth-century catalogues of authors, their names “are cited in
>   alphabetical order not of family but of first names: all the Jacobus,
>   then all the Johannes, and the Paulus, and the Petrus”.

*Source: Wilson*

Also,

> ...in the southern Netherlands “at the end of the seventeenth century,
>   the clerks of law courts and lay notaries still drew up lists of their
>   protocols in alphabetical order of first names”....Only with trade directories of the eighteenth and nineteenth
>   centuries and bureaucratic documentation from the same period does listing
>   by second name become predominant and then universal.

---

For Northern India, there does not appear to have been any widespread western influence before [the colonial period](https://www.councilscienceeditors.org/wp-content/uploads/v31n4p120-121.pdf).

> In many parts of India, there originally was no concept of using
>   surnames as understood in the Western world. Under British colonial
>   rule, however, Indians were expected to follow a naming system that
>   corresponded with the British naming convention. People in different
>   regions of India responded differently to the requirement. Indians in
>   the northern, western, and eastern regions seemed to adapt more easily
>   to the new convention.

Even today, [many Indians don't have a surname](https://www.thehindubusinessline.com/opinion/whats-in-a-name-a-lot-when-you-travel/article9555603.ece) but it's a confusing picture overall. More details can be found [here](https://www.behindthename.com/glossary/view/indian_names) and [here](http://learningindia.in/indian-naming-conventions/).

---

As previously noted, conventions vary even within western Europe so you might want to look at these two cases:

- [Spanish Naming Conventions](https://blog.myheritage.com/2011/07/spanish-naming-conventions-%E2%80%93-part-1-the-basics/)
- [The peculiarities of Icelandic naming](https://wsimag.com/culture/2248-the-peculiarities-of-icelandic-naming)

Comment: There are many unusual *family practices* that one runs across occasionally. I once knew two male cousins who were both named James Barrie [last name] - only to discover that all their brothers (three total) as well as both fathers/uncles were also named James Barrie [last name]. It was a tradition already going back three generations that all males would be named  James Barrie [last name]. I have no idea how the birth certificates were satisfied.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I can well believe that. Wilson also cites a few such examples from late medieval times so at least some people weren't interested in the practical side of having a second name!

Comment: Just to clarify: "Barrie" was the shared Middle Name and "[last name]" stands in for the shared Family Name, to protect the privacy of the guilty.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Not at all uncommon, historically. In my family tree, I have an unbroken line of five generations "Johann Heinrich [last name]". Birth and marriage certificates usually carry the year of birth as well as the full name of mother and father (at least here in Germany), so they're rather unambiguous.